# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll (int i = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();)

Tags: sql, executenonquery

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\managmentdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INFO [devices] (product_no,product_name, product_type, available_quantity, wholesale_price, sela_price)  VALUES(@product_no, @product_name, @product_type, @available_quantity, @wholesale_price, @sela_price)", con))
        {
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_n", textBox1.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", textBox2.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_type", comboBox1.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@available_quantity", textBox3.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wholesale_price", textBox4.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sela_price", textBox5.Text);
            int i = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(i + ":OK");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the code I receive the error:

> for(int i = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();)is An unhandled exception of type

Comment: Have a look at the InnerException property of the SqlClientException. This will give more detailed information.

Comment: Please clarify what language you are using.

Comment: where is for loop in your code?

Comment: `INSERT INFO `?  Try `INSERT INTO`

Comment: The language is C# and i try into but sill not solve